# Type 'File' to Type 'std::string'

Tags: c++, string, file, stream, juce

I want to put the contents of a txt file loaded by this file browser into the string 'fileLoadToString'. The conversion works when using the path in quotations.

```
FileChooser myChooser ("Please select the moose you want to load...",
                               File::getSpecialLocation (File::userHomeDirectory),
                               "*.txt");
        if (myChooser.browseForFileToOpen())
        {
            File theTextFile (myChooser.getResult());
            fileLoadToString = theTextFile;

        }
```

Here is where the 'No viable overloaded =' error message occurs. How do I convert in the correct way?

Within the main process, I want to load the string into a stream for tokenizing and further analysis.

```
std::ifstream inf(fileLoadToString);
```

Any help is always much appriciated, thank you.

```
File FileChooser::getResult() const
{
    // if you've used a multiple-file select, you should use the getResults() method
    // to retrieve all the files that were chosen.
    jassert (results.size() <= 1);

    return results.getFirst();
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `FileChooser::getResult()`

Comment: What do you mean "when using the path in quotations"?

Comment: @jamesBeilby e.g. when i declare a string i am able to fill it with the contents of a file by using = "followedbythefilename.txt"

Comment: If you are using JUCE (at a guess), you probably need to call getFileName() or getFullPathName() on the File object to get a JUCE String object. You then need to call toStdString() on that to get a std::string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myChooser.getResult` returns a `juce::File` object.  You need to read from that file object.  If `fileLoadToString` is of type `juce::String`, you can just write:

```
            File theTextFile(myChooser.getResult());
            fileLoadToString = theTextFile.readFileAsString();
```

If it is of a different type, you will have to convert the result of `readFileAsString`.